# zooming in and out an image in android

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, picasso

I have an image of size 1200x2400. I used [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to load that to my ImageView. It works good.

Now I want to have a feature to zoom in/out that image with two fingers. How do I achieve it ?

Comment: I am trying out to set onTouchListener to my imageView. Getting the events but couldn't the zoom the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) library by *Chris Banes*